# Issue with UWP packaging

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, packaging

I have 2 uwp apps App1 and App2. A uwp packaging project which refers these 2 apps. I set the entry point for App1. Now when I try to build the packaging project it throws me the following error. Please help me with this.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   APPX1101    Payload contains two or more files with the same destination path 'App.xbf'. Source files:
D:\Workspace\VSProjects\BSuite\CalendarApp\bin\x86\Debug\App.xbf
D:\Workspace\VSProjects\BSuite\MailApp\bin\x86\Debug\App.xbf    PackagingApp    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets 1822

Comment: Hello, please try to package only one app at a time. When your packag project references multiple applications, a dependency conflict may occur.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I'm trying to build an application similar to Microsoft's native mail, calendar, contacts uwp apps all bundled as single package. How will i be able to achieve this kind of bundling. At the same time I'm able to package an wpf and uwp app together but unable to do for 2 uwp apps.

Comment: Currently UWP does not support bundled installation of apps. If you have multiple apps, you need to package them separately.